# How can I take a screenshot on my Samsung Galaxy Fit?

Tags: screenshots, samsung-galaxy-fit

I can't find how to take screen shot on my Samsung Galaxy Fit device. I noticed that it took some screenshots and I do not know how it happened. By installing third party app it works, but I do not want to do this because they run their services in the background.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it served no obvious purpose. Proper nouns (such as "Samsung Galaxy Fit" and the pronoun "I") are capitalized in standard English. Your edit took a grammatically correct one and made it incorrect without adding anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Home + Power

--or--

Home + Back